# Can i Use a Fluent API Code First Model to get an IEdmModel

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, ef-code-first, odata, fluent-interface

I have a code first model built by Fluent API (System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder) that i would like to use with a Asp.Net WebApi implementation. Does anyone know a way to use Fluent API to create the IEdmModel produced in a WebApiConfig.GetModel implementation? I would like to avoid redundantly defining the model for Web.Api with an ODataModelBuilder.